# Metal band beers in Finland

Tags: specialty-beers

I will be visiting Helsinki in June. Where can I get metal band beers (Iron Maiden, Motörhead etc.).
Is it widely sold around in Finland or there is a lot of hunting to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I missing something here as I feel a bit confused about this, can someone explain a bit more please.

Comment: Some artists, including heavy metal rock bands, have dived into the craft beer craze by having beers produced and distributed with their band's label/logo. It seemed like a cheap money-grab to me until I tried Iron Maiden's Trooper Ale, which was fantastic. I have yet to try their Trooper 666 Ale or Red And Black Porter, but if their opening act is any indication, their encore is bound to be awesomely heavy, as usual.

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it.  Thanks for that, makes sense now, and yes, sounds like a money grab to me.  As a G&T drinker do you think that some orchestras would do the same thing:  The philharmonic gin for example!

Comment: "Philharmonic Gin & Tonic", has a nice ring to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get them, K-Citymarket and big supermarkets (some small have them too), and of course... Alko. Hope you're not coming to Finland just for that ahaha

Comment: Haha of course not....I'm going for a short holiday and thought of getting a few band  beers...knowing exactly where to find them would make things easier for me , would save my time and so I posted this question up....thanks a lot for the info ...really appreciate it 

Answer (score 2):

Iron Maiden's Trooper beer is British.
Motörhead's Röad Crew beer is British.

I'm not sure why you would expect to buy them in Finland.

Of course you can get them both online...

In fact, of the [heavy metal band beers listed on theblekgoat.com](http://theblekgoat.com/16-heavy-metal-beers-not-miss/), only one is from Scandinavia, and none from Finland.

- Amon Amarth's “Ragnarök” beer. USA
- Eyehategod's “In The Name Of Suffering” beer. USA
- Ghost's “Grale” beer. Sweden
- GWAR beer. USA
- High On Fire's “Razor Hoof” beer. USA
- Mastodon's “The Hunter” beer. Germany
- Municipal Waste's “Toxic Revolution” beer. USA
- Pelican's "Immutable Dusk" beer. USA
- Pig Destroyer’s “Permanent Funeral” beer. USA
- Sepultura’s Weizen. Brazil
- The Sword’s “Iron Swan” beer. USA
- Tulsadoom’s “Barbarian” beer. Austria
- Voivod’s “Kluskap O’Kom” beer. Canada

Your best bet appears to be to go to Munster, IN, where 3 Floyds Brewing Co. makes [beers for quite a few metal bands](https://www.3floyds.com/beer/toxic-maltz/).